# Left joining with multiple condition in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

| ser_1 | ser_2 | ser_3 | ser_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | name1 |
| 22 | 44 |  | name2 |
|  | 55 | 66 | name3 |
| 77 |  | 78 | name4 |
| 11 | 44 | 66 | name5 |

There is a user table:

| user_id | ser_1 | ser_2 | ser_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 2 | 22 | 44 |  |
| 3 | 22 | 44 | 55 |
| 4 | 11 | 12 |  |
| 5 |  | 55 | 66 |
| 6 | 13 | 55 | 66 |
| 7 | 77 |  | 78 |
| 8 | 77 | 22 | 78 |

And I want to get such a table:

| user_id | ser_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name2 |
| 5 | name3 |
| 6 | name3 |
| 7 | name4 |
| 8 | name4 |

For example, user_id = 3 has name2, because it has ser_1 = 22, ser_2 = 44 and ser_3 = 55, 22 and 44 create name2

I tried:

```
select u.u_id,s.ser_name
  from user u
left join service s  on (u.ser_1 = s.ser_1 and u.ser_2 = s.ser_2 and u.ser_3 = s.ser_3 )
                     or (u.ser_1 = s.ser_1 and u.ser_2 = s.ser_2 and (u.ser_3 is null or 
                                                                       s.ser_3 is null))
                     or (u.ser_1 = s.ser_1 and u.ser_3 = s.ser_3 and (u.ser_2 is null or 
                                                                       s.ser_2 is null))
                     or (u.ser_2 = s.ser_2 and u.ser_3 = s.ser_3 and (u.ser_1 is null or 
                                                                       s.ser_1 is null))
```

Comment: Where is user_id = 4 in your expected results?

Comment: This user should not be on my table,because user = 4 has ser_1 = 11  and ser_2 = 12, does not have ser_id = 13.
  If we look at the table of services, there is no ser_name that only has these two ser_id. There is only ser_id in (11,12,13) and  all create name1 not just 11 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to check whether respective ***non-null*** column values `ser_x` from **"user"**(**`u`**) match the column values of **service**(**`s`**) table, while *no matter* the *reverse perspective*(eg. ***non-null*** column values from **`s`**) *is* ...

So,
start by applying **`u.ser_x = NVL(s.ser_x,u.ser_x) AND u.ser_x IS NOT NULL`**. Moreover, there might occur cases of both sides are being ***null***, then add ***`OR u.ser_x IS NULL AND s.ser_x IS NULL`*** per each individual columns, and combine all conditions by **`AND`** as all should be satisfied at the same time.

Therefore consider using the following query

```sql
SELECT u.user_id, s.ser_name
  FROM "user" u 
  JOIN service s 
    ON (( u.ser_1 = NVL(s.ser_1,u.ser_1) AND u.ser_1 IS NOT NULL) OR u.ser_1 IS NULL AND s.ser_1 IS NULL)
   AND (( u.ser_2 = NVL(s.ser_2,u.ser_2) AND u.ser_2 IS NOT NULL) OR u.ser_2 IS NULL AND s.ser_2 IS NULL)
   AND (( u.ser_3 = NVL(s.ser_3,u.ser_3) AND u.ser_3 IS NOT NULL) OR u.ser_3 IS NULL AND s.ser_3 IS NULL)
 ORDER BY u.user_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc753f2a881fd24f1964527198c7a7ec)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a join whose conditions are *or*, not *and*:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  ser (ser_1, ser_2, ser_3, ser_name) as
  3    (select 11  , 12  , 13,   'name1' from dual union all
  4     select 22  , 44  , null, 'name2' from dual union all
  5     select null, 55  , 66  , 'name3' from dual union all
  6     select 77  , null, 78  , 'name4' from dual
  7    ),
  8  tuser (user_id, ser_1, ser_2, ser_3) as
  9    (select 1, 11  , 12  , 13   from dual union all
 10     select 2, 22  , 44  , null from dual union all
 11     select 3, 22  , 44  , 55   from dual union all
 12     select 4, 11  , 12  , null from dual union all
 13     select 5, null, 55  , 66   from dual union all
 14     select 6, 13  , 55  , 66   from dual union all
 15     select 7, 77  , null, 77   from dual union all
 16     select 8, 77  , 22  , 78   from dual
 17    )
```

Query & result:

```
 18  select u.user_id, s.ser_name
 19  from tuser u join ser s on u.ser_1 = s.ser_1
 20                          or u.ser_2 = s.ser_2
 21                          or u.ser_3 = s.ser_3
 22  order by u.user_id;

   USER_ID SER_N
---------- -----
         1 name1
         2 name2
         3 name2
         4 name1
         5 name3
         6 name3
         7 name4
         8 name4

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This query may work in this particular case, but in the real situation the same service participates in different combinations. I edited the service table and added one line, you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `INNER` join and not a `LEFT` join since you want to exclude the users that don't match.
Use these conditions:

```
SELECT u.user_id, s.ser_name
FROM "user" u INNER JOIN service s
ON  (u.ser_1 = s.ser_1 OR s.ser_1 IS NULL)
AND (u.ser_2 = s.ser_2 OR s.ser_2 IS NULL)
AND (u.ser_3 = s.ser_3 OR s.ser_3 IS NULL)
ORDER BY u.user_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c684225f3e3d0c361ee94a126d721d0d).